# Including a css file in a blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to include a css file in my Laravel blade template.

I've tried:

```
@include(public_path('css/styles.css'))
```

But it says view does not exist. It does exist.

How can I include a css file?

Please note, I know this is not the correct way to link css files, but for my use case it is (I'm not building a website).

Comment: Is it problem to you if  you write css styles in file.blade.php?

Comment: Yes it needs to be a standard .css file.

Comment: `@include` is only for views, not stylesheets. I'm not sure that the Laravel blade engine has what you need. You could create a view with a link to your stylesheet and include that view, but I doubt that is what you really want

Comment: Daniel - okay how would one include a non blade file then?

Comment: Have you tried  `{{ URL::asset('css/styles.css') }}`

Comment: HTML::style -  HTML not found and URL::asset just outputs a path not the file.

Comment: I'm thinking something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('css/styles.css')}}">`

Comment: Daniel - does not answer question.

Answer (score 96):

`@include` directive allows you to **include a Blade view** from within another view, like this :

```
@include('another.view')
```

---

### Include CSS or JS from master layout

#### [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-asset)

The `asset` function generates a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS):

```html
<link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
```

#### [`mix()`](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-mix)

If you are using versioned [Mix](http://laravel.com/docs/mix) file, you can also use `mix()` function. It will returns the path to a versioned Mix file:

```html
<link href="{{ mix('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ mix('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
```

---

#### Incude CSS or JS from sub-view, use `@push()`.

layout.blade.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- push target to head -->
        @stack('styles')
        @stack('scripts')
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- or push target to footer -->
        @stack('scripts')
    </body>
</html
```

view.blade.php

```
@push('styles')
    <link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 33):

if your css file in public/css
use :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" >
```

if your css file in another folder in public
use :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('path/css/style.css') }}" >
```

Answer (score 9):

As you said, this is a terrible way to do so Laravel doesn't have that functionality, AFAIK.

However blade can run plain php so you can do like this if you really need to:

```php
<?php include public_path('css/styles.css') ?>
```

Comment: I wanted to include the full local path so the content would be available within an email and not via a url so this was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

in your main layout put this in the head at the bottom of everything

```
@stack('styles')
```

and in your view put this

```
@push('styles')

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

@endpush
```

basically a placeholder so the links will appear on your main layout, and you can see custom css files on different pages

Answer (score 3):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/styles.css') }}">
```

It will search for the file in your project `public` folder

Answer (score 2):

just put your CSS file into `resources/css` then you need to compile it with mix
and your CSS file will be in `public/css`
use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" >
```

to refer to it ...
i recommend [this video](https://youtu.be/mEE0FzQRwGA?list=PLFHz2csJcgk_3VJwzVoeyMuC1rdBcfiLv)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers does not include the building of the `css` file. Adding the following to the `HTML`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" >
```

And adding the file `/resources/css/app.css` to the project.

Assuming it is a fresh project, running the following commands does the trick. Off course using `run prod` for the deployment build.

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this. Inside your blade

```
    <style> {{ file_get_contents(public_path('css/app.css')) }} </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of Laravel (that use Vite)

```html
<head>
  ...
  @vite("resources/css/app.css")
  ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
{{ Html::style('css/styles.css') }}
```

OR

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope this help for you !!!

Answer (score -2):

### include the css file into your blade template in laravel

1. move css file into public->css folder in your laravel project.
2. use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/filename') }}">`

so *css* is applied in a blade.php file.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/main.css') }}">

Answer (score -3):

Work with this code :

```php
{!! include ('css/app.css') !!}
```