# laravel 5.8 blade include error for big file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, include, laravel-5.8

In normal, I have a master file (amp-html project)

> localhost/windows 10/apache2.2/php7.2.2

in views root:
    master.blade.php

```
<html>
   <header>
      @yield('meta')
   </header>

</html>
```

and now I call a sub view:

in home.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('meta')
   @include('home.style')
@endsection
```

and in style.blade.php

```
<style amp-custom>

    @font-face {
       font-family: "iransans";
       src: url("fonts/irsans.ttf");
    }
    body{font-family:"iransans", sans-serif; font-size: .8rem; background- 
    color:#FFFFFF}
</style>
```

the code run without any problem.

but when I write in style.blade.php more than 400 line code, the page can not open in browser. (it loading without any error)

I google chorme developer tools in got this error

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Please read this article - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279612/including-a-css-file-in-a-blade-template/45290308`. I thin you will find the proper solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including a css file in a blade template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279612/including-a-css-file-in-a-blade-template)

Answer (score 0):

Try increase memory with ini_set

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

Comment: it's about 4000M in my system. php in server in fast but when work with laravel it is too slow...for example I can not run phpinfo()