# How to make alert with SweetAlert in Laravel

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

I would like to use SweetAlert to display my data.

I did my function

```
public function registration()
    {
        Gate::authorize('admin-level');
        $url = URL::signedRoute(
            'register',
            now()->addMinutes(20));

          return redirect('users')->with('success','$url');
    }
```

**and route that goes with it**

```
Route::get('registration', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'registration'])->name('registration');
```

**The problem** is with message, since I downloaded SweetAlert with composer I should probably got everything working, but then when I try to execute my class with button threw the route:

```
<a href="{{route('registration')}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">{{ __('Registration link') }}</button></a>
        @if(session('succes_message'))
        <div class= "alert alert-succes">
            {{session('succes_message')}}
        </div>
        @endif
```

Nothing pops up(when it should)

What might be wrong with it?

Comment: It seems you don't understand what "alerts" (also SweetAlert) and "redirecting with flashed session data" mean.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto My thinking is preety simple, when button is pressed, go to route registration > generate link > pop link in alert > go back to users view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `->with()` it means, store items in the session for the next request.

```
return redirect('users')->with('success', '$url');
```

> Here comes the question. What do you do after this?
>
> Create a **notification information** or an **alert** (popup with SweetAlert)?

If it will be used as a **notification**, your code has no problem. If you want to make **alert** (popup with SweetAlert), your understanding is wrong.

Just because the class you are using uses the name `alert`, doesn't mean it make an alert with SweetAlert.

To use [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org), you can add JavaScript in the header or before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
@if($message = session('succes_message'))
swal("{{ $message }}");
@endif
</script>
```

Or to use [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) :

```
<script>
@if($message = session('succes_message'))
Swal.fire(
  'Good job!',
  '{{ $message }}',
  'success'
)
@endif
</script>
```

If you are confused about placing the script in a specific blade view, please [read my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45290308/984422).