# css is not link successfully into laravel

Tags: css, laravel

Here is my index file in views.admin

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin/style.css">

        <title>title</title>
    </head>
```

And Here is my another file in views.admin

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin/style.css">

    <title>title</title>
</head>
```

index file is working properly but another one is not using css

AND

my css file exists at 'public/css/admin/style.css'

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45290308/984422

Comment: Are you including your second view or are they the same like this? can you provide your controller etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to link your style or script in public folder

```
{{ asset('css/admin/style.css') }}
```

Don't put the public/ folder there, if its not working add this to your .env

```
ASSET_URL = public/
```